# Interpolating within geographic boundary in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, clip, interpolation, extents

I have two layers: one is rain gauge data, another one is boundary.

I want to create rainfall distribution map within that geographic boundary in MapInfo. Can you say how to interpolate there?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Discover > Surfaces Menu > Create Grid > interactive. A dialog box appears. In that select IDW or any interpolation techniques. Provide manual extents with respect to geographic boundary. After completing we may clip the output to that geographic boundary.